# How can I return objects of different type from a single function?

Tags: java, object, return-type

I need to return objects of different classes in a single method using the keyword Object as the return type

```
public class ObjectFactory {
public static Object assignObject(String type) {

    if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("abc")){
         return new abcClass();
    } else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("def")) {
         return new defClass();
    } else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("ghi")) {
         return new ghiClass();
    }
    return null;
    }
}
```

and in another class I am trying to get the objects as

```
public class xyz{
public void get(){
    Object obj=(abcClass)ObjectFactory.assignObject("abc");
}
}
```

How can I access the methods in abcClass using the obj object??

Comment: You declare the type of the variable `obj` to `abcClass`.

Comment: Change the Object in `Object obj = ...`  to the class you are casting to: `abcClass obj = ...`

Comment: If obj must stay an Object you can cast it to the abcClass if you know that it will always be abcClass. For ex `((abcClass)obj).methodInAbcClass();`

Comment: Having this method declared to return object is a strong indicator that your code design is off base. You should fix this so that the factory method returns an object of an appropriate type, best would be an interface that covers all possible outcomes. Also you will want to learn and follow Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code will throw an exception if `assignObject` returns an instance that is not an `abcClass`, so you can change the type of `obj` to `absClass` :

```
public void get(){
    abcClass obj=(abcClass)ObjectFactory.assignObject("abc");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest as one of the commentators on your initial post did.  That is, refactor this to use an interface.

Your classes AbcClass, DefClass, and GhiClass, could all implement an interface, lets call it Letters.  You can then define a class called LettersFactory, with the method createLetters.  At this point, I'd also recommend changing your hard coded string identifiers into an enumeration.  For instance:

```
public enum LetterTypes { ABC, DEF, GHI }
```

You're factory method can then accept this enumeration, and you have no fears of getting invalid values.  The factory method can also return the type Letters (the interface) and you have a more specific version of Object (which is good).

Finally, if you need to determine these types on the fly, you can have a method defined in Letters (forcing all children to implement it) called getType() which returns the LetterTypes enumeration for the class that is implemented.

You could also use the instanceof operator to determine which class you have.

Cheers,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as a refrence :-

```
public Object varyingReturnType(String testString ){
    if(testString == null)
    return 1;
    else return testString ;
} 

Object o1 = varyingReturnType("Lets Check String");
if(  o1 instanceof String) //return true
 String now = (String) o1;
Object o2 = varyingReturnType(null);
if(  o2 instanceof Integer) //return true
 int i = (Integer)o2;
```

So similarly you can use your own conditions along with the `instanceof` operator and can cast it to get the actual object type from `Object` type.